# Primefaces extensions documentViewer not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces-extensions, documentviewer

I'm trying to use the documentViewer component from the primefaces extensions to display a PDF file, but I only get this error:

```
<pe:documentViewer> Tag Library supports namespace: 
http://primefaces.org /ui/extensions, but no tag was defined for name: documentViewer
```

I use others components from this library and they work.
Thanks in advance